# Bootstrap checkbox disables onclick functionality

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am having been trying to style my checkboxes as buttons with Bootstrap. I use the boxes for a quizz which should automatically change question when you click on a checkbox (button). This works when I remove 'data-toggle="buttons"' from my code below. But then the checkbox is within  the button. When I use the data-toggle the button is clickable but nothing happens. This is my HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="choice in question.choices" class="choices">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label for="{{choice}}" class="btn edit-set-button choicesbuttons">
            <input id="{{choice}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="option.Selected" ng-change="onSelect(question, choice);" autocomplete="off"/>{{choice}}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

My AngularJS code that switches question on click:

```
$scope.onSelect = function (question, choice) {
          question.choices.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
            question.Answered = choice;
          });

        if ($scope.defaultConfig.autoMove == true && $scope.currentPage < $scope.totalItems) {
            $scope.currentPage++;
        }
        else {
            $scope.onSubmit();
        }
    }
```